# fstream filehandling cant create an file with no error

Tags: c++

Iam trying to make my own lib (.so) with among other things a class which should create or open a file and some methodes to download or upload data in the created file with the help of the curl lib.

My first idea was to open or generate a file when instantiate the object above the constructor.

```
class myfile {
Public:
std:fstream FILE; 
...

*constructor*
myfile (const char * filename)

myfile.open(filename,..some flags..) 
{
  If(!myfile.is_open()){
  Error Handling
}
```

So stupid Idea cause in the constructor I havent allocated memory for myfile::FILE and naturally I cant open the file, are my thoughts about thats are right?

So I had changed that I made a myfile::create () method.

Which I called after the constructor in my main function.

main:

```
mylib::networkfile * volatile test = NULL;
test = new mylib::networkfile("test.txt");

test->create();
```

mylib::networkfile:

```
networkfile::networkfile(const char *filename)
{
    this->filename.assign(filename);
}


void networkfile::create()
{
  FILE.open(name.c_str(),std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | 
                  std::ios::binary | std::fstream::app);
  if(!FILE.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "Datei: " << name.c_str() << " cant open/create file" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

So if I execute the programm I get my opening/create error but strangely no Error from <errno.h>.

-rwxrwxrwx test and also for mylib.so are given

Someone see my problem?

Comment: this->~datafile();  Doesn't look right at all, don't do that, maybe set a flag file wasn't opened so that other calls will fail too but don't destroy this.  Also note you don't have to type this-> everywhere.

Comment: Okay thanks so my memory fault now is gone :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay my misstake, i used this flags to open my file:
std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary | std::fstream::app

I changed it to this std::ios::binary | std::fstream::app and now it will work fine,  I have yet to find out why.

Comment: `trunc` and `app` have the opposite effect, what did you expect to happen?